# I am trying to make a simplify method that nodes on my AST

Tags: java, calculator, abstract-syntax-tree, simplify

I would like to create a calculator in Java. I have some problem implementing the simplify method. For example, I have the expression 5 * 2 + x + 3 / 4.
The AST tree would look like this:

[image: AST]

The output would look like 10 + x + 3 / 4. We simply 5 * 2 but not 3 / 4 since we want only exact numbers not doubles (no decimals). And x doesn't change because we have not define the value for x.

My skeleton code should look like this:

```
public static AstNode simplify(Environment env, AstNode node) {
    return new AstNode(simplifyHelper(env.getVariables(), node));
}

private static double simplifyHelper(IDictionary<String, AstNode> variables, AstNode node) {
    // There are three types of nodes, so we have three cases.
    if (node.isNumber()) {
        // TODO: your code here
    } else if (node.isVariable()) {
        if (!variables.containsKey(node.getName())) {
            // if value for variable not define, leave as it is
        }
        // TODO: your code here
    } else {
        String name = node.getName();

        // TODO: your code here

        if (name.equals("+")) {
            // TODO: your code here
        } else if (name.equals("-")) {
            // TODO: your code here
        } else if (name.equals("*")) {
            // TODO: your code here
        } else if (name.equals("/")) {
            // TODO: your code here
        } else if (name.equals("^")) {
            // TODO: your code here
        } else if (name.equals("negate")) {
            // TODO: your code here
        } else if (name.equals("sin")) {
            // TODO: your code here
        } else if (name.equals("cos")) {
            // TODO: your code here
        } else {
            throw new EvaluationError("Unknown operation: " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if in the simplify helper method, should I return AstNode or double? I tried using double but when diving it should not return a double since we don't want to deal with divisions when simplifying.

Comment: Since you have a few things you can't simplify to `double`, `AstNode`  seems to be a better choice.

Comment: yes that is what i thought. can you please help me on the pseudo code pls? should i use a recursive function or what?

Comment: I don't have resources to write your code for you. Yes, recursion is not a bad idea. I personally would define a number of simplification or rewriting rules. Like "if this is `*`, `+` or `-` operation and leaves are numbers, perform the operation and return a node holding the result". Or "for n-ary operators, order number nodes first". Then I'd apply these rules to all the (applicable) nodes as long at least one of the rules was applicable.